# whats the exact rule in function declaration in c++

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

I want to know is it mandatory to have constant arguments in the functions.
Recently I had in interview and wrote a code like below

```
int numofsubstring(string s1, string s2)
{
   int nCount =0;
   size_t pos;
   while((pos = s1.find(s2)) != string::npos)
   {
     nCount++;
     s1 = s1.substr(s1.find(s2)+s2.length());
   }
    return nCount;
}  //number of times s2 is present in s1
```

The panel was expecting const string&s1 ,const string&s2 but i didn't wrote bcz of substr functionality usage...

can any one guide what's the standardised format to write the code....
the panel was insisting to improve the arguments in the function.

Comment: There are no "rules". But passing those strings by value is wasteful, there is no need to have a copy of either string.

Comment: Why does using `substr` stop you from passing the parameters as `const std::string &`?

Comment: The function return type is `void` so this function won't even compile.

Comment: you need to read about pass-by-value vs pass-by-reference. They keypoint about their complaint wasn't the `const`

Comment: The underlying message from the panel may have been missed - it's better to have _reference_ arguments in your function, because copying the strings is unnecessary.  And making those references `const` allows for broader usage of the function.

Comment: Let's take it apart.  The `std::string&` says that the parameter refers to the original variable passed by the caller.  When you make changes to the parameter, you are changing the caller's variable.  The compiler does not make a copy.  The `const std::string&` means that the parameter refers to the caller's variable and the function won't modify the caller's variable.  Your function will make copies of the caller's variables.

Comment: substr will slice of the s1 data right..hence didnt used the const string&...

Comment: No, `substr` will copy the substring into a new string object

Comment: I understood, now I have modified the question little bit ....can you review it now

Answer (score 0):

No it is not mandatory to have constant arguments in the functions. Note that the function you wrote is using `pass by value`. While if you had function parameters as `const std::string&` then it is `pass by reference`.

One of the reason for using `const std::string&` version is that in this case there will be no "copying" of passed strings, so it is **faster**(for very long strings) than the pass by value version.

Also in the case of `pass by value` the arguments passed will be copied and each of the argument will be destroyed after the function scope ends. This destruction part will not happen in the `pass by reference` version.

**Edit:**
If you want that the arguments passed to the functions should not be changed inside the function body then you can add `const`. Below is the way to make the arguments `const` that is they cannot be changed inside the function body anymore.

**WAY 1**

```
//pass by value, now that we have added const the arguments s1 and s2 cannot be changed inside the function body
int numofsubstring(const string s1, const string s2)
{
//some code here
}
```

**WAY 2**

```
//pass by reference, now that we have added const the arguments s1 and s2 cannot be changed inside the function body 
int numofsubstring(const string& s1, const string& s2)
{
//some code here
}
```

Comment: Sir I understood and now i have little bit modified the code ...shall you review and suggest

Comment: Do you have any particular question from the modified code? And can you also mention the aim or what you're trying to achieve in the modified code.

Comment: sir my question is , is it mandatory to have const type arguments for function....
In modified code...the source s1 is changing the value bcz of substr....so how shall i keep it as const...

Comment: @ManjunathaR I have made an **EDIT** to my answer which shows how to make the arguments const that is not changable. In WAY 1 the arguments are `const string` while in WAY 2 they are reference to const string.

Comment: Yes sir,I knew those things....but observe the line below

`s1 = s1.substr(s1.find(s2)+s2.length());`

which will modify the content of string s1....in this case how shall i write const...
else I have to copy it in temporary string ??

Comment: @ManjunathaR Yes you would have to make a copy of `s1` when entering the function body. You can do `string tempstring = s1;` and then use this `tempstring` instead of `s1` if you don't want `s1` to change. This would look like `tempstring = tempstring.substr(tempstring.find(s2)+s2.length());` and `while((pos = tempstring.find(s2)) != string::npos)`.

Comment: @ManjunathaR You can mark this answer correct if this helped you.

Comment: Its correct answer sir but I don't have reputation to mark correct. Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: @ManjunathaR You can click the "tick mark" shown at the left side of the answer. Reputation is needed only for voting up or down. No Reputation is needed for marking the answer as correct. These are 2 different features of stackoverflow. You can still click the "tick mark" on the left side. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

To the extent that there is "a rule" the rule would be

> if you have some function that takes a `T` and you can pass a `const T&` instead without affecting correctness then you should pass a `const T&`.

It's about eliminating unnecessary copies. Passing a references is like passing a pointer. Nothing gets copied so the performance of the function will be better.